# Can not run my tests in C# Selenium with Specflow(1.9)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, specflow

c# selenium project with BumbleeBee used for POM and Specflow(1.9) when I ran the test I get this error :

> Could not find test executor with URI
>   'executor://specrun.com/executor_v1.2'.  Make sure that the test
>   executor is installed and supports .net runtime version

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code and configuration.

Comment: I was able to fix it with with installation of SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation package